# Kohana ORM Caching/Caching design approach

Tags: caching, kohana-orm, kohana-3.2

This questions is related to Kohana ORM *AND* Caching module. I use version 3.2 if it matters. I tried to research trust me, but I really couldn't find some good answer... so here it is:

1. What are the correct ways to use `ORM::cached()` and `ORM::serialize()` and `ORM::$reload_on_wakeup`?
   I've seen many 2-line code examples but never anything really solid on the userguide/api...
2. What is the difference between enabling Cache module and `'caching' => true` in `Kohana::init`?
3. Anyone has any recommended approach for the following specific situations? I have a catalogue page that upon profiling, I realized two very expensive actions:

   - I queried database each time for a currency model for each item, when the currency information can really be reused.
   - I queried database each time for each item's inventory item, this is an expensive query, which I wish I can cache until inventory level changes.

References that I found but couldn't answer fully my questions:
http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/1782/tip-for-caching-orm-objects/p1 
http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/10600/does-kohana-orm-and-cache-work-together/p1

Answer (score 0):

Just found your question, maybe too late, but maybe is useful to others:

1. cached, will force the Query builder to cache the DB query. It uses the KOhana:cache method (file cache) I am trying to find a workaround for this.
2. enables caching for the file search as says in the Kohana/Core.php file: Whether to use internal caching for [Kohana::find_file], does not apply to [Kohana::cache]. Set by [Kohana::init]
3. Enable caching true to speed up the file search, and enable the cache module, I am working on a way to cache the queries of DB using the instance used by the module. That would be better than using the file cache. Maybe I am missing something but stuck there right now.